# Problem importing a SVG logo

Tags: svg

I'd like to make a simple animation with an extruded logo.
I've traced the vector logo and saved it into SVG format, then I imported it into Blender.

Everything seems fine, beside the off-centered origin, that's an easy fix.
But once I enter edit mode, I don't see what I'd expect to.
Any ideas on what's happening?

[image: screenshot]

Non edit-mode in yellow box.

Comment: Hello :). These are just curve normals. I'm not sure where to disable them in 2.79, but setting the curve as 2D should help too.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this out. Thank you.